# gcc compilation flag

Tags: gcc

can any body explain me why we use -m flag in gcc ?
I run man gcc command result are quite unclear can any body explain me role of this flag in compilation?
how to use -m flag its proper syntax?
i need it because i'm running a auto generated makefile through make command but it shows an error which is following: 
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-m"
can anybody explain what is that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-m` is always followed by a `machine-option`, which will typically be machine-dependent. Common examples are `-m32` and `-m64` for selecting 32 bit and 64 bit builds on architectures which support both.

It sounds like you have an empty or uninitialised makefile variable somewhere.