# C++ compile issue

Tags: c++, gcc

```
meme@ubuntu:~/Data$ g++ UDPEchoServer.cpp PracticalSocket.cpp -o udpskserv -lsocket -lnsl -mt
```

I trying to compile at my compiler ubuntu and i receive this error

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mt’
```

May i ask what is -mt , i try google but can't find any information.

If I try omit the -mt parameter i get this error

```
PracticalSocket.cpp: In constructor ‘SocketException::SocketException(const string&, bool)’:
PracticalSocket.cpp:33:38: error: ‘strerror’ was not declared in this scope
PracticalSocket.cpp: In function ‘void fillAddr(const string&, short unsigned int, sockaddr_in&)’:
PracticalSocket.cpp:47:32: error: ‘memset’ was not declared in this scope
PracticalSocket.cpp: In member function ‘void Socket::setLocalPort(short unsigned int)’:
PracticalSocket.cpp:119:42: error: ‘memset’ was not declared in this scope
PracticalSocket.cpp: In static member function ‘static short unsigned int Socket::resolveService(const string&, const string&)’:
PracticalSocket.cpp:153:32: error: ‘atoi’ was not declared in this scope
PracticalSocket.cpp: In member function ‘void UDPSocket::disconnect()’:
PracticalSocket.cpp:291:40: error: ‘memset’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Did you include `<stdlib.h>` or `<cstdlib>` in PracticalSocket.cpp?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you don't know what `-mt` is, why are you using it?

Comment: There are two separate problems here. To make things working, pls remove -mt and fix the compile errors.

Comment: This might help with the "-mt": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802799/gcc-compilation-flag.

Answer (score 14):

Both `std::memset` and `std::strerror` are declared in the `<cstring>` header, you need to `#include` that one.

And GCC does not have a `-mt` option.